# Nike No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, http, nike

I'm trying to get the current men clearance shoes from the Nike store site using Angulars $http request and display it on my own site.

```
 $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://store.nike.com/html-services/gridwallData?country=US&lang_locale=en_US&gridwallPath=mens-clearance-shoes/'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('success',response);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('error',response);
    });
```

However, it gives me this error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://store.nike.com/html-services/gridwallData?country=US&lang_locale=en_US&gridwallPath=mens-clearance-shoes/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know its a Cross-origin resource sharing issuse.  Is there any way to by pass this?  And also can I legally display their clearance products on my site?

Comment: *"And also can I legally display their clearance products on my site?"* we can't answer that. *"Is there any way to by pass this"* Yes, the same way as described in many of the other identical questions regarding bypassing CORS restrictions.

Comment: why not?  their api is public can I use it on my own site?  should i ask it in stacklaw instead?

Comment: because we aren't lawers, we can't give you legal advice (and if we do you shouldn't trust it)

Comment: well.. they aren't usually lawers either.

Comment: If their web service supports it, you may be able to use [jsonp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42641/JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy) to work around the cross origin problem.

Comment: thanks I guess I'll just use it for personal use

Comment: yes u can use there data as this is open

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
   myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: which server are u running?

Comment: sorry didnt see.  I'm running a node server.  I was able to get the data using an jQuery ajax call instead.